# How to solve this error in selenium?

Tags: automation, automated-tests

i write the code to test the sign up form and i am getting this error for browser.

**ERROR:-**

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to 
              connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.
```

**gcr.java class:**

```
package SeleniumWebdriver;

//import java.util.Date;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class gcr {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.gcrit.com/build3/");
  driver.findElement(By.linkText("create an account")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bodyContent']/form/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]")).click();
  driver.findElement(By.name("firstname")).sendKeys("piyush");
  driver.findElement(By.name("lastname")).sendKeys("kansal");
  driver.findElement(By.name("dob")).sendKeys("10/01/1993");
  /*Date date=new Date();
  int x=date. getSeconds();*/
  //String Email= "piyush@gmail.com";
  driver.findElement(By.name("email_address")).sendKeys("piyush@gmail.com");
  driver.findElement(By.name("street_address")).sendKeys("innotical");
  driver.findElement(By.name("postcode")).sendKeys("251001");
  driver.findElement(By.name("city")).sendKeys("noida");
  driver.findElement(By.name("state")).sendKeys("Up");
  Select Dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("country")));
  Dropdown.selectByVisibleText("India");
  driver.findElement(By.name("telephone")).sendKeys("9958097200");
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("9958097200");
  driver.findElement(By.name("confirmation")).sendKeys("9958097200");
  driver.findElement(By.id("tdb4")).click();

  String Message = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bodyContent']/h1")).getText();
  if (Message.equals("Your Account Has Been Created!")) {
   System.out.println("Account has created-passed");
  } else {
   System.out.println("Account not created-failed");
  }
  //driver.close();
 }

}
```

Comment: is the port already in use elsewhere?

Comment: I find it odd that the connection error is for your computer's loopback address (127.0.0.1). Is this page hosted on the computer from which you are running the tests? Am I completely off here?